# How to make TagLib# work on a file with the wrong extension?

Tags: c#, .net, tags, taglib, taglib-sharp

I'm using *TagLib#* to retrieve meta data from my MP4 file. So far, so good, everything works fine, until I spotted a file with a "wrong" extension" that made LagLib# puke. I discovered this file was saved with a jpg extension and it made TagLib throw exception **Expected SOI marker at the start of the file.** After [some googling](http://www.google.nl/search?cx=w&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=Expected%20SOI%20marker%20at%20the%20start%20of%20the%20file.) I discovered that this has to do with reading jpeg files.

If I look at the magic number for the file it returns `00 00 00 20 66 74 79 70`, which corresponds with the correct [signature for mp4](http://www.garykessler.net/library/file_sigs.html).

I've got the following questions:

1. How can I read the meta data without renaming the file.
2. How does TagLib# determine meta data?

Any ideas?

Ps. The code I used was like this:

```
string file = @"D:\vs2008\Inetpub\wwwroot\Test\data\AA028578_7_2.jpg";
TagLib.File tag = TagLib.File.Create(file);
Console.WriteLine(tag.MimeType);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can specify the mime type (force it):

```
string file = @"D:\vs2008\Inetpub\wwwroot\Test\data\AA028578_7_2.jpg";
TagLib.File tag = TagLib.File.Create(file, "video/mp4", TagLib.ReadStyle.Average);
Console.WriteLine(tag.MimeType);
```

I don't know how it is loaded in TagLibSharp.

Comment: Well, I can always use my magic number sniffer, but I would like TagLib to do something like this.

Comment: You could also use `TagLib.Mpeg4.File.Create(file);`.

Comment: @KeesC.Bakker have you found how to do it with TagLib? or did you just write  "video/mp4" MimeType in Create method as suggested?

Answer (score 0):

```
TagLib.File.Create(file, "audio/mp3", ReadStyle.None)
```

worked for me